# Why did James Potter let Dumbledore borrow his invisibility cloak, knowing his child's life was in danger?

Tags: harry-potter, albus-dumbledore, invisibility-cloak

Couldn't the invisibility cloak be used to sneak out baby Harry when Voldemort finds out Harry's location? If yes, then why did James let Dumbledore borrow it?
Also the question can be: why did Dumbledore borrow it knowing that baby Harry's life was in danger?

It seems like plot convenience to me that Dumbledore had *conveniently* borrowed the cloak to examine it at the time when James needed it the most. Is there a good reason for this?

Comment: other than that the Potter's thought they were perfectly safe and protected by the Fidelius Charm? Remember, they didn't know their location was revealed by the very person they trusted to keep them safe. Also - we've seen that the cloak isn't entirely immune to magical penetration [Moody's eye could see through it]

Comment: @NKCampbell we know that the Fidelius charm could be compromised by the secret keeper(and was).  Also James being an auror himself and user of the cloak since childhood(maybe) must have known about the cloaks credibility and there is no mention that Voldemort can see through the cloak when even Dumbledore couldn't *exactly* see through the cloak himeself.

Comment: I'm just saying - it stands to reason that the Potters felt themselves reasonably more safe via the Fidelius charm in one location than trying to be on the run with three people and a cat under a cloak..and they didn't know Voldemort knew where they were until it was far too late for the cloak to be any use anyway

Comment: @NKCampbell Why are you assuming that the whole family would hide under the cloak? it is also possible that only one either James or Lily would use the cloak sneaking out baby Harry with them while the other would try to distract Voldemort sacrificing themselves(as Lily eventually did).

Comment: James an auror? Was he?

Comment: *"The invisibility cloak you that you inherited from your father, and he from his father, appears to be longer-lived, more durable and effective than most.  Do you mind if I, Great Wizard and Prestigious Magical Researcher that I am, could study it to try and improve other cloaks for the Order of the Phoenix?"*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Potters were protected by the Fidelius Charm, they had no need of the Invisibility Cloak, and they surely didn't expect Petter Pettigrew to turn to Voldemort and tell him the secret.

Besides that, the Invisibility Cloak wouldn't have protected them, as Harry wisely states:

> ‘The Cloak wouldn’t have helped them survive, though,’ Harry said
> quickly. ‘Voldemort knew where my mum and dad were. The Cloak couldn’t
> have made them curse-proof.’
>
> ‘True,’ sighed Dumbledore. ‘True.’
>
> <sub>Rowling, J.K.. Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows (p. 584).
> Pottermore Publishing. Edición de Kindle.</sub>

Voldemort knew where they were. He could've performed a simple *Homenum Revelio* to detect the Potters, and then blast them away with whatever curse he wanted. He could've simply blasted down the house with the Potters inside.

He could've done a lot of things, even if James still had his Invisibility Cloak.